# Is there a way to protect yourself against Naga Siren's ultimate?

Tags: dota-2, dota

Is there a way to prevent your hero from getting asleep from Song of the Siren?

Comment: BKB comes to mind however I have not tested.

Comment: BKB does work according [to this thread](http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=49224)

Comment: I dont know much about Dota2 but I played enough Dota 1 to know that any other Magic Immunity will work (Omniknight's shield comes to mind as strong b/c he can cast on others).

Comment: Naga's ultimate is one of the few ultimates that go through BKB same like reaper's scythe and battle roar and swap and many other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

BKB, Omniknight's Repel, Lifestealer's Rage, Juggernaught's Blade Fury, and the Earth Element of Brewmaster's ulti.

Edit: The first being obtainable on any Hero, the rest being situational as 'counter picks' against her.

Comment: This is the more complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Dota2 wiki.

BKB (Black King Bar) is sure way of not being put to sleep

source:- http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Naga_Siren